# System.Threading and number of threads in a CPU core

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-cores

Is the number of threads created using `System.Threading` depends on physical threads in a CPU? Is there a direct one to one relationship between the two?

Let's say if I create 10 threads as below while the CPU has 4 cores and 8 threads, does this mean only 8 threads will run simultaneously while for other 2 threads, CPU will do task switching?

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
```

Comment: That declaration just allocates 10 `Thread` objects and doesn't actually start any threads -- for that you'd need `Thread.Start` -- but yes, you can't have more threads running simultaneously than the hardware supports. In fact, the OS will switch between threads even if you don't have more than the hardware supports, as your application is never the only thing running. Every `Thread` you create represents a new, kernel managed thread; if you want flexible scaling, use the thread pool (either directly or using `Task`s).

Comment: Depends on what you call simultaneously. Yes, only 8 threads can execute CPU instructions at the same time. But the others can still e.g. do I/O. There doesn't even have to be a 1:1 fixed mapping even between OS threads and .NET threads, much less hardware "threads". What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am calling an asynchronous messaging queuing service. If each call takes around 1 second then 1000 calls will take 16 minutes so I was trying to reduce it by calling 10 threads at a time which will reduce time to 1.6 minutes (assuming I/O and other things remain the same)

Comment: A cheap way of parallelizing things to the system's capacity without explicitly managing threads is to use parallel LINQ (`Enumerable.AsParallel`), `Parallel.ForEach` or (slightly more complicated) [dataflow components](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). However, you should establish first if you can actually scale up calls this way -- if the queue is an in-order one or based on a database, you may well find that parallel calls don't actually scale and you need to batch requests instead.

Comment: If you open up Task Manager and click the performance tab, how many threads does your system already have before your program starts? Mine has over 3000 threads already.  Do you think your 10 threads will make much difference?  Maybe, but as long as you code it properly, you will probably find that the bottleneck is I/O rather than CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create threads just to wait for I/O to complete.   The `async/await` pattern will help you, by waiting for the I/O to complete, whilst freeing up those threads to do other useful work.

The other thing to bear in mind is that if you call your other service 10 times (or 100 or 1000) at the same time, if that service is also waiting for I/O, then it's possible that you could still take 16 minutes to complete your tasks.